# how to text wrap the tooltip in ag-grid in angular 6

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

[please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M47K7.jpg)

is there any way to wrap the text inside ag-grid in angular.in the image the tooltip is not fully visible since it is a long text. i tried using customTooltip but its not worked also i have tooltip for all columns as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom cell renderer component using `ICellRendererAngularComp`

and pass that in your column definitions.